# What does java.lang.Object@19821f means in Java?

Tags: java

What does java.lang.Object@19821f means ? This is the output when I try to print the variable of Object type without any Assignment. code:

```
Object object = new Object();
System.out.println(object);
```

Comment: It is Object's default `.toString()` implementation. Nothing fancy, as you can see, and which is why you should override `.toString()` in your classes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support println in a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647567/how-to-support-println-in-a-class)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Answer (score 4):

RTFM, [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   `toString` method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.
>
> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns **a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character '@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object**. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

It's important to note that behind the scenes, `System.out.println` invokes the `toString` method of its argument.

Answer (score 0):

It's just what the `toString()` method outputs for the `Object` type. It's (currently) specified to be:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Because `Object` is the uber-class for all objects, it could be *any* type of object, so it's expected that derived objects will override the `toString()` method to provide a more useful representation.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default implementation of `Object.toString()`.  You can even look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.toString%28%29) for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the hashcode of the Object that you just instantiated. the println method just calls the Objects toString method.